# I Can't drop database in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

When I excute db.dropDatabase() in my Mongodb database,I got this error:

```
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.dropDatabase()
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "timed out waiting for C_XXXX-movePrimary",
    "code" : 46,
    "codeName" : "LockBusy",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1575187253, 6),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1575187244, 78)
}
```

This cluster used seven shards and three replica set,I have checked db.currenOp(),and kill ops on this database,Then I excute  db.dropDatabase() again,But the command stucked. just like this:

```
> MongoDB Enterprise mongos>db 
C_XXXX 
MongoDB Enterprise mongos>db.dropDatabase()
...nothing output...
```

I am new for mongodb.And I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. 
Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. 
Thinks.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [official Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.dropDatabase/)

**You need to select a database first**

> **Example** 
>   The following example in the mongo shell uses the use
>    operation to switch the current database to the temp
>   database and then uses the db.dropDatabase() method to drops the temp
>   database:

```
use temp 
db.dropDatabase()
```

Comment: Yes,I did it like this,but no use.Thanks any way.

Comment: hope it resolves your problem. Don't forgot to upvote if it's an accepted answer, Happy Coding!!